# double left join in sql?

Tags: sql

I'm revisiting SQL because I started a new project.

I have 3 tables (only useful fields shown):

**Player:**
id

**Fines**
player_id, fine

**Finelist** id, price

I want to get the total fine for each player. I'm struggling with adding in the price for each fine.

`SELECT p.id, COUNT(f.player_id)
FROM PLAYERS p LEFT JOIN FINES f ON (p.id=f.player_id)
GROUP BY p.id`

returns the right amount of fines for each player. Now I have different fines with different prices. Now I want to add those in. I tried it like this:

`SELECT p.id, COUNT(f.player_id) * fl.price
FROM PLAYERS p LEFT JOIN FINES f ON (p.id=f.player_id), FINELIST fl
WHERE fl.id = f.fine
GROUP BY p.id`

Now it only takes the first row of FINELIST into account. Only the rows in FINES with `fine = 1` get added to the COUNT.

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible in one query and would like to get some help.

Comment: use SUM() instead

Comment: also, you may need to show sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do a left join with FINELIST too.  Should look like this:

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  COUNT(*) as fine_count,
  SUM(COALESCE(fl.price,0)) as total_fine
FROM PLAYERS p 
LEFT JOIN FINES f ON p.id=f.player_id
LEFT JOIN FINELIST fl ON fl.id = f.fine
GROUP BY p.id
```

> I put the coalesce in there because on some systems using `SUM()` on a null value will give a warning or error.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT p.id, SUM(fl.price)
FROM PLAYERS p LEFT JOIN FINES f ON (p.id=f.player_id), FINELIST fl
WHERE fl.id = f.fine
GROUP BY p.id`

Did the trick.